# guidata() doesn't return user data in figure callback (GUIDE)

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I'm creating a GUI where I want to bind a function to `WindowButtonUpFcn` of the GUI itself. First I store my struct in `hObject` like so:

`guidata(hObject,pm)`

I then want bind a function to the callback mentioned above like so:

`hObject.WindowButtonUpFcn = @(varargin) WindowButtonUp(hObject);`

Now inside that callback I try to retrieve my struct

```
function WindowButtonUp(hObject,varargin)
    pm = guidata(hObject);
    % Some calculations
    guidata(hObject,pm);
end % I put this here for syntax highlighting, generally this is not necessary
```

`pm` now contains

```
figure1: [1x1 Figure]
 output: [1x1 Figure]
```

While it should contain

```
pm = 

     Axes_Hndls: [1x3 Axes]
    Spline_Hndl: [1x3 Line]
      DragIndex: 0
          Plane: [1 2]
           Mode: 1
              n: 100
     Point_Data: [3x3 double]
    Point_Hndls: [3x3 GraphicsPlaceholder]
```

Which doesn't make sense to me. `hObject` contains

```
  Figure (figure1) with properties:

      Number: []
        Name: 'gait_editor'
       Color: [0.9400 0.9400 0.9400]
    Position: [181 27.6667 209.5000 64.7333]
       Units: 'characters'
```

What am I missing here? I can not pass the struct directly to the callback since it calls other functions which expect `hObject` (where the `guidata()` function **does** work.

Comment: It would be helpful is you show the relevant parts of "Some calculations" that involve `pm`

Comment: @Suever How would that be relevant? As soon as I try to retrieve `pm` from `guidata()` it doesn't contain what it should. The calculations are not relevant.

Comment: Ok well there's not enough info to help you out. Identify all calls to `guidata(hobject, pm)` in your code and put a `disp(pm)` before them to figure it out. You're assigning it bad data somewhere. Also do you have more than one figure?

Comment: @Suever Well the problem is that right before the callback definition I test if it works with `pm = guidata(hObject)` and it returns fine. Immediately after that it's passed as an argument to the callback and it breaks. So there's not really any place for me to check anything anymore. I have a feeling it has to do with some recursion issues.

Comment: Maybe it would help to make your callback be `@(src, evnt)WindowButtonUp(src)` instead to ensure the *right* object is passed?

Comment: @Suever it shouldn't matter, `guidata` always stores to the figure window. Assuming he only has one figure window...

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @excaza Right but as I said it's not clear if there is one window or two since `pm` contains two figure references.

Comment: @Ortix92 - Is your GUI created using GUIDE?  If so, you probably have a function figure1_OpeningFcn that sets guidata to a structure with fields figure1 & output.

Comment: @grantnz yep that was it.